# How to pass the parameter to same page using java script in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to pass the parameter to same page using java script in Asp.net

`top.location.href = '/IFGE/DeleteAllPrice/' + id;`

is working fine for redirecting to other pages but not working for redirecting to same page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "?ID=" + someid ;
```

You need to append window.location.href

Comment: This is likely a more correction option: `'//' + location.host + location.pathname + "?ID=" + someid;`  -- with that one you can repeatedly call the page without getting the old parameters passed.

Answer (score 3):

What if the page url already has "?" or includes some parameters. The selected answer would result to a malformed URL since it just appended to some existing queries. Do this instead;

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.split("?")[0] + "?ID=" + someid ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you try to refresh/reload the page?

Try one of this:

- window.location.reload();
- history.go(0);
- window.location.href=window.location.href;

Answer (score -3):

Its better to Use AJAX with http - Post method, and post parameter to the Server.

Something like: (Do Not copy and paste below code. Please research more on this procedure)

```
var myObject = new Object();
myObject.FirstName = "david";
myObject.LastName = "Jones";
XmlHttpRequest vXHRequest = new XmlHttpRequest();
..
..
..
vXHRequest.send(myObject);
```

in asp.net aspx page page_load,

```
Dictionart dict = JavaScriptSerializer.DeSerialize<Dictionary>(Request.Params["myObject"]);
```